# armazenar valores e exibi-las em outro campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

gente desenvolvi esse [site](http://agenciafront.com.br/medicalseg/) e na parte de indenizometro tem um fade.js onde quando o usuário clicar em um dos botões leva ele ao passo seguinte
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ao fazer isso ira aparecer um pequeno formulário que ele terá que digitar essas informações e ao clicar em próximo ele ira pegar essas informações e inseri-las no passo seguinte só que não sei com fazer isso é possível ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as informações dos inputs serão exibidas nessa etapa abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: ele não será armazenado em banco é só para exibir na hora mesmo. preciso fazer isso via jQuery ou JS

Segue meu código php e js:

PHP:

```
 <div class="box-informations">
                                <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                    tempor
                                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                                <h4 class="subtitle">Selecione a causa: <i class="fa fa-question-circle"
                                                                           aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </h4>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline indenizometro-list">
                                    <li class="list"><a class="link -morte">Morte</a></li>
                                    <li class="list"><a class="link -invalidez">Invalidez</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            {{--Event morte--}}
                            <div class="box-informations-morte">
                                <h4 class="title">Causa: <span>Morte</span></h4>
                                <p class="subtitle">Insira os dados do paciente</p>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" id="mail"
                                               placeholder="DIGITE A IDADE"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"
                                               placeholder="SALARIO ATUAL"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="btn-next-morte">Próximo</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box-protected-morte">
                                <img src="img/info-segurado.png" class="img-responsive img-segurado"/>
                                <p class="subtitle">Valor da indenização</p>
                                <h3 class="price"><span>R$</span>35.000,00</h3>

                                <a href="{!! route('indenizometro') !!}" class="btn-protected-morte">Proteja-se!<br/><span>Avançe para avaliar seu seguro</span></a>
                            </div>
                            {{--End event morte--}}

                            {{--Evend invalidez--}}
                            <div class="box-informations-invalidez">
                                <h4 class="title">Causa: <span>Invalidez</span></h4>
                                <p class="subtitle">Insira os dados do paciente</p>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" id="mail"
                                               placeholder="DIGITE A IDADE"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"
                                               placeholder="SALARIO ATUAL"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="btn-next-invalidez">Próximo</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box-protected-invalidez">
                                <img src="img/info-segurado-2.png" class="img-responsive img-segurado"/>
                                <p class="subtitle">Valor da indenização</p>
                                <h3 class="price"><span>R$</span>25.000,00</h3>

                                <a href="{!! route('indenizometro') !!}" class="btn-protected-invalidez">Proteja-se!<br/>
                                    <span>Avançe para avaliar seu seguro</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            {{--End Event invalidez--}}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box-informations-morte").hide();
    $(".box-protected-morte").hide();
    $(".box-informations-invalidez").hide();
    $(".box-protected-invalidez").hide();

    //morte
    $(".-morte").click(function(){
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-morte").fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    $(".btn-next-morte").click(function(){
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-morte").hide();
        $(".box-protected-morte").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    //end morte

    //invalidez
    $(".-invalidez").click(function(){
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    $(".btn-next-invalidez").click(function(){
        $(".box-informations").hide();
        $(".box-informations-invalidez").hide();
        $(".box-protected-invalidez").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    //end invalidez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, você pode utilizar o LocalStorage ou SessionStorage para armazenar isso e recuperar posteriormente. Segue um exemplo

```js
$('.tipo').on('click', function(){
   sessionStorage.setItem('tipo', $(this).attr('data-tipo'));
})
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('nome', $('input[name=nome]').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem('idade', $('input[name=idade]').val())
    $('.result').append('<p>'+sessionStorage.nome +' - '+ sessionStorage.idade +'</p>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome">
<input type="text" placeholder="Idade" name="idade">
<a class="tipo" data-tipo="Invalidez">Invalidez</a>
<a class="tipo" data-tipo="Morte">Morte</a>
<button class="btn">VAMOS LÁ</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta no caso como são 2 inputs como ficaria o código ? a sim e o meu botão e um link com uma class  e nao um <button> como ficaria isso tbm na chamada no button no JS

Comment: @Kirito editei o codigo

Comment: @Kirito conforme for mais campos é só ir seguindo a mesma logica,

Comment: daora so mais uma dúvida no caso na primeira etapa so tem 2 botões com de morte outro de invalidez a escolha tem que ser salva tbm no local storage poderia me mostrar como ficaria o código tbm por favor ? 
esse são os links ele devem aparecer tbm na ultima etapa
<li class="list"><a class="link -morte">Morte</a></li>
                                <li class="list"><a class="link -invalidez">Invalidez</a></li> a sim e o resltado final teria que ter um titulo exemplo idade - 33 anos por exemplo no caso se eu deixar como esta so vai aparecer 33

Comment: @Kirito você quer que ao clicar nele salve tambem?

Comment: não amigo só isso mesmo porque depois vai ter uma validação e vai ser salvo em uma base de dados só quero deixar dinâmico para apresentar para o cliente nao precisa salvar eu quero que ele fique igual o resultado da terceira imagem do meu post  me desculpa por isso é que sou muito novato nessa area de programação

Comment: no seu link você coloca assim <a class="link-invalidez" data-tipo="invalidez">Invalidez</a>

sessionStorage.setItem('tipo', $(this).attr('data-tipo'))

Comment: você coloca isso dentro do clique do botao

Comment: legal ai para fazer a chamadinah dele no apend ficaria assim $('.result-morte').append('<p>'+sessionStorage.idade +' | '+ sessionStorage.salario +' | '+ sessionStorage.morte +'</p>')

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem('morte', $(this).attr('morte')) meu data-tipo eu coloquei o nome de morte ai eu so substituo onde esta screito tipo por morte certo ?

Comment: Certo, se a resposta te ajudou, por favor, marcar como resolvido e dar +1 :D

Comment: ajudou sim amigo obrigado mesmo so que fica dando undefined haha

Comment: $('.btn-next-morte').on('click', function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('idade', $('input[name=idade]').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem('salario', $('input[name=salario]').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem('morte', $(this).attr('data-tipo'))

        $('.result-morte').append('<p>'+sessionStorage.idade +' | '+ sessionStorage.salario +' | '+ sessionStorage.morte +'</p>')
    });

Comment: meu código nao funcionou a parte do data-tipo fiz algo errado ?

Comment: @Kirito sim, você fez errado, vou atualizar o codigo

Comment: @Kirito atualizei, você precisa usar exatamente como fiz a cima

Comment: te amo cara vc é o melhor ahahha

Comment: Amigo se eu precisa-se adicionar um botão de voltar como ficaria poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @Kirito Explique melhor

Comment: Na verdade eu já consegui so que tipo quando eu clico em voltar e em proximo de novo os dados duplicam da uma acessada no meu site e logo na home você  vai ver a sessão indenizomrtro clica em morte e segue os passos quando chegar no botão cinza grande você vai ver um link para voltar ao clicar nele e depois clicar em proximo de novo você vai ver que ele duplica os dados  e ai mais nao quero isso quero que quando clica-se em coltar aquele campo se limpem  esse é o link do site http://medicalseg.com.br/